# find command and tar

Tags: shell, find, tar

```
find /informatica/dev/SrcFiles* -mtime +7 -and -size +1M -exec tar -cvjf>
```

So I ran this command and I can't find the file after it was done running (probably because I never named it?). The directory contains thousands of files.

Where do I put the name of what I want the `.tar` to be called?

Does anybody know where the tar file gets made and put or what it's called after I run it?

Comment: Did you really have that `>` at the end? That makes the command syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 2):

```
find /informatica/dev/SrcFiles* -mtime +7 -and -size +1M -exec tar rvf file.tar {} \;
```

where `file.tar` is your archive name.  If your use the option `c` with `tar`, it will *create* a new archive for each file, overwriting the previous one.  If you use `r`, it will *append* to the previous archive.

Comment: okay so when i find the files and want to put them all in the tar file, I should use the r option only?

Comment: Yes, you need to change `c` to `r`.  If you have too many file in the directory, use `ls -ort` to search for the most recent ones.

Comment: Actually its not doing anthing `/informatica/dev/SrcFiles> find /informatica/dev/SrcFiles* -mtime +7 -and -size +1M -exec tar rvf files.8.2.2013.tar {} \;`

Comment: What happens when you issue the command without the `-exec` part?

Comment: @unxnut Is the `-and` really necessary? I believe it's implied.

Comment: That is correct @JosephR.  `-and` is implied.

Answer (score 1):

You should have referred to the tar man page, simply by issuing the command:

```
man tar
```

For your specific question, here is a good example of how to do it:

```
 find /informatica/dev/SrcFiles* -print0 -mtime +7 -and -size +1M | xargs -0 tar cjvf /mydir/mytarfile.tar.bz2
```

This way, the tar command will be called only once, instead of being called each time a file is found.
Notice the `-print0` and `-0` arguments. This will avoid word splitting ...

Also, you should make sure that the archive is not placed in the same directory, while its name may come up in the search pattern. You will get an error suggesting that you can't add an archive to itself!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use star as star comes with a builtin find. This enables features that cannot be achieved with a separate find command.